# Select distinct and non-distinct column values

Tags: sql, oracle, select, group-by, distinct

I want to run a query that eliminates duplicate rows based on the values of colA and colB.
However, I still want to return the values of colC and colD.

Here is a simple example of what I have so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT colA, colB   ?colC, colD?
FROM TABLE1
```

or

```
SELECT colA, colB    ?colC, colD?
FROM TABLE1
GROUP BY colA, colB
```

Either method does not allow me to return colC, and colD unless I check them as distinct values or group like colA and colB.  I do not want to do this, only colA and colB together need to be distinct not colC and colD.  I just want to return them.

Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Assuming that there are multiple rows in `table1` with a particular set of values for `colA` and `colB`, which set of `colC` and `colD` values do you want returned?  The minimum values?  Maximum values?  The "first" or "last" values (in which case you'd need to tell us how to order the data so that "first" and "last" are meaningful)?

Comment: Can you post some sample data and the desired result?

Comment: @JustinCave Can you elaborate a bit more on how I would use "first" and "last"? I believe I would always want the first value.  How would that look with my example?

Comment: @Baxter - "First" and "last" relies on having some way to order the data.  If there are two rows in `table1` with identical `colA` and `colB` values, how do you know which is the "first" row?  Is there some additional column (a timestamp, for example, or a monotonically increasing `table1_id`)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do you want `list_agg`?

```
select colA, colB,
       list_agg(distinct colC, ','),
       list_agg(distinct colD, ',')
from Table1
Group by ColA, ColB
```

If any arbitrary value would do for ColC and colD, you can use `min()`:

```
select colA, colB, min(colC), min(colD)
from Table1
Group by ColA, ColB
```

Comment: I think any arbitrary value will work for me in this case.  I will give min a try on the columns I do not wish to group by.

Answer (score 2):

The DISTINCT applies to all values you are selecting, not just to some columns. In your case it will apply to all: colA, colB, colC, colD. It is impossible to select all columns and make some distinct and some not. The only way to do this shown in Gordon's example, this is the only valid example and answer.

Comment: I agree. I tried using min for the columns that I don't care about being unique or ordered.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use plain set operations

with UNION and UNION ALL 
(see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries004.htm)

UNION colA and colB will eliminate doubled entries in these columns whereas UNION ALL will keep all values from the colC and colD